# Is there a way to know when someone tries to guess your gmail password?

Tags: email, account-security, gmail

Is there a way to check if someone is trying to login to my Gmail account without knowing the password (so they keep trying to guess the password and failing repeatedly or trying to guess the answers of account recovery) as opposed to trying to login and getting the password right? (I know Gmail warns you when that happens).

Comment: I don't think so, or everyone would receive dozens and dozens of messages all the time.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that by yourself, obviously if you had access to the gmail server, then it would be trivial to check. Maybe it's possible to contact gmail staff for this, but I doubt they are giving that info unless required by a court order or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no it is not possible view these logs unless you have a google business account.

If you do have a google business account it can be viewed via the admin panel.

More Info here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3287/137301